# What is best practice for returning an array to client side from a Meteor server method?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to return a MongoDB cursor from a MeteorJS server side method. I can return the array to the server side but can't figure out how to pass it back into the client. What's the best way to do this?

```js
//current server side
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        'mongo.updateSearchQuery' (searchQuery) {
            var queryCursor = remoteEvents.find({
                $text: {
                    $search: searchQuery
                }
            }).fetch()
            console.log(queryCursor);
            return (
                queryCursor
            )
        }
    });
}

//current client side
callMongoTextSearch() {
    var searchQuery = this.state.searchQuery;
    var searchQuery = Meteor.call('mongo.updateSearchQuery', searchQuery);
    console.log(searchQuery);
}
```

Comment: Why use a method instead of pub-sub?

Comment: I'm certainly open to using Pub-sub, I didn't realise this would allow me to dynamically change the query.

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to the publication just like a method. Unlike a method however the result is reactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a **callback** as the last argument of your [`Meteor.call`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call) in order to use the returned result from your server `Meteor.methods`. Whatever you *return* in your `Meteor.methods` will be passed as the 2nd argument of your callback.

For example:

```js
Meteor.call('mongo.updateSearchQuery',searchQuery, function (error, result) {
  console.log(result); // result will be your `queryCursor`
});
```

You should probably also make sure you get the concept of asynchronous tasks, e.g. [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Assigning result to `searchQuery` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments, makes sense!